# All applications do not respond when I try to print

Tags: windows, printing, printer

I used a broken printer to print now all applications can no longer print. When I hit print in any app, the app no longer responds.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I fix it? This isn't rocket science @BenN

Comment: You self-answered, so you solved the problem for yourself, which is great.  However, your question contains no detail and could cover a range of possible problems.  For someone else with a similar problem, your solution might not be relevant.  Can you expand your question to provide more detail about your specific situtation, for which your answer was a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Hit the windows start button

type run, hit enter

type services.msc , hit enter

find Print Spool.

Stop and Start Print Spool

This will clear all interactions with your printers

Comment: I think his references to "app" indicate he's not in Windows, but in Android or something.

Comment: @Alex He is the OP, so we can assume he meant windows ... ;)